# Site rendering broken on iOS and Mac OSX after moving to JDK 10 and JSF 2.3 with WildFly

Tags: ios, macos, primefaces, wildfly, omnifaces

Good day

Issue below is solved on WildFly 13 by disabling HTTP/2 (while still keeping TLS for HTTPS).

Even the non effected browser and system combos (all the non Apple stuff) seem to load much faster now.

Follow instructions from this post on how to disable HTTP/2:

https://developer.jboss.org/message/984394?et=watches.email.thread#984394

From the ./jboss-cli.sh cli just run:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:write-attribute(name=enable-http2,value=false)
```

And reload / restart the server. All devices render perfectly and fast.

I am leaving the below if somebody else runs into a similar error.

I updated my code and POM file to use the Java EE 8 dependencies for WildFly 13 based on the WildFly 13 BOM POM and the @Balusc JSF 2.3 Java EE 8 kickoff sample application.

So I set it to use:

- JSF 2.3.5.Final
- OmniFaces 3.1
- PrimeFaces 6.2.7

On desktop (all operating systems with all of the latest browsers) the site works 100% and the war is deployed in half the time.

However the site fails to render correctly on my iPhone. I tried all browsers installable from the app store, and the one that looks the nearest to correct is Firefox.

However even with Firefox I can't get pass the login screen.

On Android and all non Apple based products the site works without any error logs.

Is anybody aware of issues rendering JSF 2.3 on Apple based products?

Any pointers on what to look for, add or change will be most appreciated.

See below for log file info:

The initial error only triggered from iOS / Mac OSX is an UNDERTOW error with OmniFaces info (we are using TLS for HTTPS, but before moving all to JSF 2.3 everything worked 100% with zero errors or warnings in logs)

```
2018-07-30 09:09:18,741 ERROR [io.undertow] (default task-3078) UT005085: Connection io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2ServerConnection@7e55834 for exchange HttpServerExchange{ GET /edsnext/javax.faces.resource/omnifaces.js.xhtml request {accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8], accept-language=[en-us], :authority=[edsnext.megchemsa.com:62543], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], :path=[/edsnext/javax.faces.resource/omnifaces.js.xhtml?ln=omnifaces&v=3.1], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1], :scheme=[https], cookie=[JSESSIONID=U5X9u-A83bccAnpA1XUnEFzmngqI9iDJwuIiU_Qo], :method=[GET], Referer=[https://edsnext.megchemsa.com:62543/edsnext/], upgrade-insecure-requests=[1], Host=[edsnext.megchemsa.com:62543]} response {Expires=[Mon, 30 Jul 2018 09:57:18 GMT], ETag=[W/"5933-1532705069245"], Last-Modified=[Fri, 27 Jul 2018 15:24:29 GMT], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=U5X9u-A83bccAnpA1XUnEFzmngqI9iDJwuIiU_Qo.edsnext; path=/edsnext], Content-Type=[application/javascript], Date=[Mon, 30 Jul 2018 07:09:18 GMT], :status=[200]}} was not closed cleanly, forcibly closing connection
```

Then the following PrimeFaces resource not found warnings (and login page is rendered incorrectly on iOS)

```
2018-07-30 09:09:21,056 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3091) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, fa/fontawesome-webfont.eot, from library, primefaces.
2018-07-30 09:09:21,056 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3084) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, fonts/lato-regular-webfont.svg, from library, primefaces-omega.
2018-07-30 09:09:21,056 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3082) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, fa/fontawesome-webfont.ttf, from library, primefaces.
2018-07-30 09:09:21,056 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3100) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, fa/fontawesome-webfont.svg, from library, primefaces.
2018-07-30 09:09:21,056 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3103) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, fonts/lato-bold-webfont.svg, from library, primefaces-omega.
2018-07-30 09:09:21,056 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-3091) : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

EDIT: Added log file info pointing to UNDERTOW errors followed by lots of PrimeFaces missing resources.

EDIT 2:

Ok, I tested this with:

Server side:

- CentOS 7.5 all updated
- Oracle JDK 10.1
- WildFly 13.0.0.Final
- JSF 2.3.5.SP1
- PrimeFaces 6.2.7
- OmniFaces 3.1

The following setups renders the site perfectly with zero errors or warning at debug level:

- CentOS GNOME 7.5 Chromium
- CentOS GNOME 7.5 Firefox Developer Edition
- Windows 10 Chrome
- Windows 10 Firefox Developer Edition
- Android Studio Nexus 5 AVD APK 28 Chrome
- Samsung Galaxy S7 Chrome
- Samsung Galaxy S7 Firefox

All browsers installable from the Apple app store including Safari fails to render the site. All have the UNDERTOW error.

Tested with Mac OSX - latest updated version - also fails with the UNDERTOW error.

I logged a bug report with Apple. Problem is though that a substantial amount of users are effected by this due to having to access the Web app via their iPhone or iPad.

What else can I do to expedite this?

Comment: I can't seem to reach your site even from a desktop Chrome.  I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OU

Comment: It is definitely up, however it only has a 30Mb/s link and is in the southern hemisphere

Comment: I am also able to ping the server currently, so it is definitely up.

Comment: And **ALL** browsers on the 'closed' apple phones use the same rendering engine. So if one fails, all fail (thank you apple for giving us a choice)

Comment: @Kukeltje that sucks indeed.  I will try to download an Android emulator. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, sorry, but the site looks the same on my desktop firefox and android firefox.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for testing the site on your phone. It is most probably an iOS bug then. I am busy downloading the Android SDK. Does Chrome on your mobile also render correctly? Although if Firefox on Android renders the login screen as a modal append to body dialog then it works. iOS cannot do that. It just renders the dialog in the top left corner.

Comment: Looks the same on Chrome mobile too.

Comment: @Kukeltje Sincerest thanks for confirming it. So definitely an iOS bug then. Wondered what causes this, as with JSF 2.2 it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Letholdrus it worked perfectly in JSF2.2 with PF 6.2.7?  Just wondering if its a PF issue or a Mojarra JSF issue.

Comment: @Melloware Not sure, there are no error messages on the server logs and I don't have access to an Apple SDK IDE or Mac to enter development mode in the browser.

Comment: Maybe "Content Security Policy 2.0" is related in some way?

Comment: @Kukeltje Good day, do you imply that prior to JSF 2.3 CSP 1 was used but JSF 2.3 uses CSP 2? If so, how can I go about setting it back to CSP 1 for JSF 2.3 to test?

Comment: No, sorry it was misleading. I meant that CSP in general could be related (1, 2, whatever) and it might be worth investigating. I just scanned the features of Safari and noticed this CSP2.0 thing and just copied it verbatim

Comment: @Kukeltje I see, will investigate. I also removed the answer post and added it as an edit to the main post.

Comment: If you remove omnifaces, does it work then? if not, remove it from the tags please

Comment: @Kukeltje Unfortunately OmniFaces is such an awesome must have and use library that the app will completely fail to compile if I remove it due to it being used on all JSF files... Is there a running live demo version of the Kickoff app from BalusC to test against. I can only build the kickoff app and run it on localhost, not accessible from the outside on my phone

Comment: I'm not stating to remove it definitly from your project, just from a [mcve] to narrow down if it plays a role in this issue. That is what tags are for, not what you use.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, I got that. However I don't have permission (from the systems guys) to deploy a MCVE so that it would be accesable via the internet so that I may connect to it from my phone. I can't even connect my phone to the same Wi-Fi network in order to test it on localhost with WildFly set to use -b=0.0.0.0 Hence the question 'is the JSF 2.3 Kickoff app available as a demo from the internet?' i see it is at http://javaeekickoff.omnifaces.org/ according to https://github.com/javaeekickoff/java-ee-kickoff-app/tree/javaee8-jsf23 However the demo site just loads and never shows anything?

Comment: Tried to access http://javaeekickoff.omnifaces.org/ from various devices but seems like the site is down?

Comment: @Letholdrus just to be sure you are not using PrimeFaces Mobile or have this line anywhere right?  <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE">
You just have a regular PrimeFaces site with responsive elements for IOS?

Comment: @Melloware Yes you are 100% correct. The only JSF libraries I have in the POM file and use are: PrimeFaces 6.2.7, PrimeFaces Extensions 6.2.7 and OmniFaces 3.1 Only use PrimeFaces native components, not the Deprecated PrimeFaces Mobile taglib. To add some more info, the site still work 100% correctly as it should when logging in using an Android VD or Samsung S7. But any iOS device fails to render even the login page correct and the submit button to authenticate does nothing... Very weird indeed.

Comment: I am stumped it has to be something in Wildfly 13 that is sending something back to the IOS browser that it doesn't like.  I hope you can get it figured out!

Comment: @Melloware Thanks, I will try to deploy on Payara and see if the problem is still there. Will keep you updated.

Comment: I've brought http://javaeekickoff.omnifaces.org back. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC the kickoff site works perfectly on iOS. I am seeing an Undertow error in the logs when connecting via iOS. Don't have details of the error code now, will post back on Monday.

Comment: @BalusC Good day Mr Scholtz; I added log file info. We are using TLS for HTTPS and the first error seems to be an UNDERTOW error saying that OmniFaces resources could not be loaded. Not sure if this is the actual error or a side effect of the actual error. Still investigating. Hopefully the log file info can assist others as well with a possible suggested solution.

Comment: Are you using HTTP/2? Try disabling it...

Comment: @Kukeltje I am using HTTPS with a CA issued certificate. Unfortunately I will not be able to remove HTTPS, or replace it with a self signed certificate.

Comment: PLEASE read my comment... _**HTTP/2**_ (HTTP slash 2, not HTTPS) Although different server, maybe related: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/2625

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks will read now. I was able to get onto the local LAN with my phone and connected to a normal HTTP session from my iPhone. Works 100%, fast, beautifully rendered with no warnings or error in any logs.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks yes, that appears to be the same issue / related issue. Connecting via HTTP completely remove the issue. From your link I am not entirely sure what was meant with disabling PUSH on JSF?

Comment: Its disabling push on http/2. not related to jsf/primefaces/omnifaces push/websockets. Remarkable that both glashfish and wildfly have a problem with this. Background article about http/2: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the extra info, much appreciated, busy reading it.

Comment: @Kukeltje Went through the docs. Are there anything from my side I can do thus to resolve this issue, or do I need to wait for the WildFly guys to provide a fix or Apple to fix their HTTP/2 PUSH implementation?

Comment: No idea how to go from here, sorry. Might still be related to Mojarra (maybe you can check if MyFaxces has the same problem or not to exclude things).

Comment: disabling http/2 can help (and still do https!)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, much appreciated, will investigate that option.

Comment: @Kukeltje It is resolved! I will update the initial post with how to disable HTTP/s on WildFly 13 while still keeping TLS HTTPS. Sincerest thanks for nudging me along to the fix.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not like an old fasioned dicsussion forum which is abused as Q&A engine. There's absolutely no need to prefix "SOLVED" in titles. Stack Overflow is a fullworthy Q&A site and already offers built-in facility to make a question appear as "solved", simply by accepting an answer. Either ask @Kukeltje to post it or post your own.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this error disable HTTP/2 on WildFly 13 with:

Follow instructions from this post on how to disable HTTP/2:

https://developer.jboss.org/message/984394?et=watches.email.thread#984394

From the ./jboss-cli.sh cli just run:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:write-attribute(name=enable-http2,value=false)
```

Restart / reload the server and all is well.

Comment: Tried with MyFaces too by accident?

Comment: Sorry @Kukeltje haven't had the chance yet. Will do as soon as I get the gap.